# Session in Webserver

Tags: java, session, web-applications, sessionid

Can anyone give me link or describe me, How Webservers recognize the continuous requests are coming from same user.
Or How webserver maintains sessions not any application.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways via cookies, via hidden fields or session objects. google for 'session management using cookies, using hidden fields, using session objects. you'll get the links.

Comment: Webservers typically maintains it with sessionID returned to the user in cookies or in querystring

Answer (score 0):

Check articles:

[IBM WebSphere Session Management](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=332851&seqNum=2)

[Secure Session Management With Cookies for Web
Applications](http://www.isecpartners.com/files/web-session-management.pdf)

[HTTP Session Management in Weblogic](http://cafe-o-babe.blogspot.com/2009/03/http-session-management-in-weblogic.html)

Answer (score 0):

Each session has unique id.
Server recognize user by this id. It can be passed for example via cookies or in get parameter in url...